# Lbl2vec on google colabo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-colaboratory

how can i run this Lbl2vec library on google colab since google colab using  python 3.7 and this library requires python 3.8 or above also
by installing the new python version on google colab it is still unable to run on the colab note book

i have tried
#install python 3.9
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2

!python --version
python 3.9.12

and then instaling pip ny get-pip.py
but nothing is happeing
please help ....!

Comment: i guess there is a pip installation issue..if someone can guide in this regard thankyou

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AlexB I am unable to run this Lbl2vec library on google colab completely. since this Lbl2vec does not support python 3.7 version which is by default on colab...i am installing python 3.9 but still it does not work